# stripe pci compliance for handing credit card information

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a form where I collect the credit card information, send it over https line to my server. In the server, I am using Stripe PHP library to generate a token and store it in my database. Can you please suggest me whether I have followed PCI Compliant or Is there any PCI checklist available in the web?

Thanks,
Raja K

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, this is not compliant. By sending raw card data to your servers, you are responsible for the highest burden of PCI compliance, the [SAQ D](http://pcipolicyportal.com/saq-a-d/saq-d/).  SAQ D is the most onerous of all the SAQs, with over 40 pages of requirements you must implement to remain PCI compliant.

The easiest level of PCI compliance is a Pre-filled SAQ A, which you can use if you use Stripe's frontend libraries to tokenize card data. I would recommend looking into [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) to see if they fit your needs.

With Checkout or Elements, Stripe's libraries will tokenize a card for you, and you can send that token to your servers to create a charge.  This means that the standards for PCI compliance no longer apply to your servers, as they don't contain sensitive card data.

You can read more about the different levels of PCI compliance when using Stripe here:
https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance